# Setup Outlook IMAP without SMTP

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How do you set a IMAP account in Outlook without SMTP? I need to be able to archive emails from a old email account that has since been moved to Office 365.

I can not find any information past Outlook 2010 that says if you use POP3 you can skip the "test account" and still download the messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook 2010 was the only program that worked as it should. When I entered "normal" in the SMTP server fields and once all the other fields were completed did the option to skip the account check become available. All other Outlook versions I tired always had the Account Check grayed out even with "normal" as the SMTP server.

I think its a little stupid how the newer versions of Outlook only allow this with IMAP configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You may use any other SMTP server that you have, or a free one that you may find
on the internet.

By default Outlook will use the same user/password for outgoing and
incoming servers, so be careful to specify different credentials for the
SMTP server.

---

To disable the SMTP check, try this:

- Enter Outlook menu
  *File > Options > Advanced > Send and Receive section*
- Click the "Send/Receive" button.
- Select the "All Accounts" group from the Group Name list
- Click the "Edit" button to open the dialog
  "Send/Receive Settings - All Accounts"
- Uncheck "Send mail items"
- Click OK
- Click Close and again OK.

---

Another possibility:

- Enter Outlook menu
  *File > Info > Account Settings > Server Settings > Outgoing mail*
- Uncheck "My outgoing (SMTP) server requires authentication"
- Click Next

Comment: I have tried other programs and only Filezilla will download the messages but I need to import them into Office 365. Filezilla changes the metadata making this useless in O365.

Its the SMTP check I'm looking to disable. I have tried to setup another SMTP account in there and it still fails. 

Surely it can't be this hard to just download messages and save them to Archive.

Comment: Then you have asked the wrong question. You should have asked about transferring email from Outlook to to Office 365.

Comment: No I asked the right question. There are no messages in Outlook to transfer. I need to know how to setup Outlook to download the messages.

Comment: If Outlook insists on an SMTP server, just give it one, or I don't understand the question.

Comment: It fails the Test Account check because when it sends a email the email is not received. This is because DNS has already been cut over to Office365. I need to turn off the freaking SMTP check otherwise Outlook will not accept the account.

Comment: OK, I added two possibilities. I don't use Office 365, but hopefully this is the same as in Outlook 2019.

Answer (score -1):

According to my knowledge, when adding the email account, we will always need to input POP/IMAP and SMTP server information. After adding successfully, as a workaround, we can configure it as a receive account.

Please check the details in this article: [Exclude account from receiving (send only account)](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/308).